# Bad block detection in SD card using SPI interface?

Tags: sd-card, spi

I know that SandDisk Micro SD cards have bad block detection and re-mapping capability.  The default mode for an SD card is the 4 bit SD interface. When using the SPI interface does anyone know if the SD card will still do this automatic bad block detection and re-mapping? Based on my reading the SanDisk OEM Product Manual

"The SPI Mode is a secondary communication protocol for cards in the SanDisk
microSD Card Product Family. This mode is a subset of the SD Protocol, designed to
communicate with an SPI channel, commonly found in Motorola and other vendors'
microcontrollers. Detailed information about SPI Mode can be found in Section 7 or
the SDA Physical Layer Specification, Version 3.01."

This does not seem to clarify my doubt. Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using a different interface with the card should not prevent the card from doing its internal wear leveling and bad block management as the commands do not change, only the physical link.

From section 7.1 of the Physical Layer Simplified Specification Version 4.10

> The SPI standard defines the physical link only, and not the complete data transfer protocol. 
>   https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/part1_410.pdf